# jquery pass option for height, outHeight, etc

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could I modify this plugin so that I can pass the type of height calculation I would like to use. E.g `height()` or `outerHeight()` or `innerHeight()`

```
/*! 
* equalHeightColumns.js 1.0
*
* Copyright 2013, Paul Sprangers http://paulsprangers.com
* Released under the WTFPL license 
* http://www.wtfpl.net
*
* Date: Thu Feb 21 20:11:00 2013 +0100
*/
$.fn.equalHeightColumns = function(options) {
    defaults = { 
        minWidth: -1,               // Won't resize unless window is wider than this value
        maxWidth: 99999,            // Won't resize unless window is narrower than this value
        setHeightOn: 'min-height',   // The CSS attribute on which the equal height is set. Usually height or min-height
        heightMethod: 'outerHeight'
    };
    var $this   = $(this); // store the object
    options     = $.extend({}, defaults, options); // merge options

    // Recalculate the distance to the top of the element to keep it centered
    var resizeHeight = function(){

        // Get window width
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();

        // Check to see if the current browser width falls within the set minWidth and maxWidth
        if(options.minWidth < windowWidth  &&  options.maxWidth > windowWidth){
            var height = 0;
            var highest = 0;

            // Reset heights
            $this.css( options.setHeightOn, 0 );

            // Figure out the highest element
            $this.each( function(){
               // height = $(this).height(); BEFORE
                height = $(this).eval(options.heightMethod);
                if( height > highest ){
                    highest = height;
                }
            } );

            // Set that height on the element
            $this.css( options.setHeightOn, highest );
        } else {
            // Add check so this doesn't have to happen everytime 
            $this.css( options.setHeightOn, 0 );
        }
    };

    // Call once to set initially
    resizeHeight();

    // Call on resize. Opera debounces their resize by default. 
    $(window).resize(resizeHeight);
};
```

See the part where I have added `$(this).eval(options.heightMethod);` I cant get the syntax correct

Comment: I am planning on setting this so that each element can pass the heightMethod as a data attribute, but for now I just want to get the basics working with default settings

Comment: Just do `$(this)[options.heightMethod]();`? Be sure that you validate the heightMethod's value for occasional wrong input, e.g. `Outer_Height`, etc.

Comment: The option to use several height-methods is already there, look at "heightMethod" in the defaults array.

Comment: @akluth I believe the OP already added that option (note the failing comments behind it) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you've missed the comment,

`$(this)[options.heightMethod]();` should do the trick, though be sure that you validate the heightMethod's value for occasional wrong input, e.g. Outer_Height, etc.

Validation could be quickly done by simply checking if the function you're calling e.g. `outerHeight`, exists.

```
if(typeof $(this)[options.heightMethod] != "undefined")
  $(this)[options.heightMethod]();
else
  // some warning / error.
```